# Databinding ListBox to a List of a Class that Contains a navigation Property Of Other Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, listbox

I have the following classes

```
public partial class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserDetail
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind the property of `UserDetail` called `Name` in datatextField of listbox its given error property not found.
Basically, i am having a list of `User`, in which there is a navigation property of `UserDetails`.

My Code is

```
if (Session["AllUsers"] == null)
{
    LoadDataForUser();
}

var lstUser = (List<Entities.User>)Session["AllUsers"];

ddlEmployees.DataTextField = "UserDetail.Name";//I am getting Error here
ddlEmployees.DataValueField = "UserID";
ddlEmployees.DataSource = lstUser;
ddlEmployees.DataBind();

ListItem li = new ListItem("--Select Users--", "-1");
ddlEmployees.Items.Insert(0, li);
```

Help Required!! Anyone please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing it like this:

```
if (Session["AllUsers"] == null)
{
    LoadDataForUser();
}

var lstUser = (List<Entities.User>)Session["AllUsers"];

ddlEmployees.DataTextField = "UserName";//I am getting Error here
ddlEmployees.DataValueField = "UserID";
ddlEmployees.DataSource = from user in lstUser
                           select new { user.UserID, UserName = user.UserDetail.Name };
ddlEmployees.DataBind();

ListItem li = new ListItem("--Select Users--", "-1");
ddlEmployees.Items.Insert(0, li);
```

Comment: its still giving exception  does not contain a property with the name 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[VStM.Entities.User,System.String]'.

Comment: Can you debug and check if there is a value for name in the user.UserDetail property ?